# using wild card to git show

Tags: git, shell

I am trying to use wildcard in git show as shown below.

```
git show h3223459:./data/path/to/fullfile.csv
```

The above command works. However when I try to use the wildcard it throws an error message.

```
git show h3223459:./data/path/to/*file.csv

fatal: Path 'data/path/to/*file.csv' does not exist in 'h3223459'
```

Is there any way to pass wildcard in git show. I tried wild card in git checkout and it works fine there.

Answer (score 0):

`git show` takes arguments acceptable to [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), which does not include pathspecs.  It does allow paths, as shown [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrevgtltpathgtemegemHEADREADMEememREADMEememmasterREADMEem) and as used in your successful command.

(Oddly, I don't get the `fatal` error, I just see `git show` silently show nothing:

```
$ git show 'b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a:*kefile'
$ git show 'b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a:./*kefile'
```

The error seems better.)

> I tried wild card in git checkout ...

The `git checkout` command accepts *pathspec* arguments, [as documented not-quite-so-well here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) and described in [the gitglossary](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec).  These do accept wildcard matches by default.